# Android webview links open in default browser

Tags: android, browser, android-webview, hyperlink, default

I have a scenario where links in my webview should open the default android browser. I searched regarding this and I got to know that if we are setting the custom webviewclient in our webview and load the url in shouldOverrideUrlLoading method, then it will not work.
But in my case, I need to extend the WebviewClient in the webview since I am doing some cookie management and loading some javascript code. May I know how I can use both functionalities together?

Answer (score 0):

If you set a WebViewClient to your webView you can use it's `onPageStarted` or `onPageFinished` methods to perform the actions that you want. Both methods receive the url as a parameter, so this allows you to send this url to the default android webbrowser.

`startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));`